# VBA: Referencing a defined data type element using a variable

Tags: vba

I'm trying to reference an element of a user defined type using a variable...

```
Type pTest
  Name As String
  Age As Double
End Type

Global Test(2) As pTest

Sub ArrayRef()

 A$ = "Name"

 Debug.Print Test(0).A$

End Sub
```

I imagine the answer is simple, but I can't seem to find it. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something more like?

```
Option Explicit

Type pTest
  Name As String
  Age As Double
End Type

Global Test(2) As pTest

Public Sub ArrayRef()
 Dim a$
 a$ = "Name"
 Test(0).Name = a$
 Debug.Print Test(0).Name
End Sub
```

The alternative, which you use with classes, if you are trying to use a string variable as the property argument would be:

```
CallByName(Test(0), a$, VbGet)
```

Which won't work due to Test(0) not being an object. And I don't think you can pass a user-defined type.

Comment: Thanks for the swift reply. I'm trying to use a variance to reference an element, so is there an equivalent to CallByName for user-defined types?

Comment: You can't AFAIK. See if some of the boffins confirm that.

Comment: So I guess you could create a custom class.